# Sql XML to Delphi

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, delphi

Good morning , for those who is still morning ..

I got a project to do and i have the following : 
I got a `SQL TABLE` with 4 columns , lets call them `C1,C2,C3,C4` ,this columns have some data that i need to Delphi and from here i need to call a C# function with this parameters ex : `SQL TABLE XML -> DELPHI -> C#function(c1,c2,c3,c4)`

I don't know how to parse the XML to Delphi....

```
SELECT * FROM ExportModelMacheta FOR XML AUTO
```

I use this but i don't know what i should do after , i have the xml in a new sql window but how i'm suppose to parse it . Should i use a `TXMLDOCUMENT` ?  but this have the parameters to get only a File Path , so how i'm suppose to give him the `xml` ? I was thinking that i should make a query in Delphi in which i would call this select and save the everything in a string , then look in that string for what i want and extract them , but is a lot of work to do and i guess there should be a better way to achieve this .
It would be easy if i would have a file to give the path but i was told that i need to make everything from sql...

This is the xml code that i should get in delphi in order to call my c# function

```
<ExportModelMacheta Macheta="ufImportProduesPrioritateXContactare" NumeColoana="IdArticol" TipDeDate="string" Pozitie="1" FromatMacheta="xls" />
<ExportModelMacheta Macheta="ufImportProduesPrioritateXContactare" NumeColoana="Prioritate" TipDeDate="string" Pozitie="2" FromatMacheta="xls" />
<ExportModelMacheta Macheta="ufImportExcelCaracteristiciUtilizatorXContactare" NumeColoana="IdUtilizator" TipDeDate="string" Pozitie="1" FromatMacheta="xls" />
<ExportModelMacheta Macheta="ufImportExcelCaracteristiciUtilizatorXContactare" NumeColoana="IdLocatie" TipDeDate="string" Pozitie="2" FromatMacheta="xls" />
<ExportModelMacheta Macheta="ufImportExcelCaracteristiciUtilizatorXContactare" NumeColoana="TipUtilizator" TipDeDate="string" Pozitie="3" FromatMacheta="xls" />
```

Comment: Why do you want to go via xml when Delphi does an excellent job of talking directly to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ExportModelMachetas = new object[][] {
                new object[] { "ufImportProduesPrioritateXContactare", "IdArticol", "string", "1"},
                new object[] { "ufImportProduesPrioritateXContactare", "Prioritate", "string", "2"},
                new object[] { "ufImportExcelCaracteristiciUtilizatorXContactare", "IdUtilizator", "string", "1"},
                new object[] { "ufImportExcelCaracteristiciUtilizatorXContactare", "IdLocatie", "string", "2"},
                new object[] { "ufImportExcelCaracteristiciUtilizatorXContactare", "TipUtilizator", "string", "3"}
            };
            List<XElement> results = ToXML(ExportModelMachetas); 

        }
        static List<XElement> ToXML(object[][] ExportModelMachetas)
        {
            List<XElement> results = new List<XElement>();

            foreach (var ExportModelMacheta in ExportModelMachetas)
            {
                XElement newExportModelMacheta = new XElement("ExportModelMacheta", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("Macheta", ExportModelMacheta[0]),
                    new XAttribute("NumeColoana", ExportModelMacheta[2]),
                    new XAttribute("TipDeDate", ExportModelMacheta[2]),
                    new XAttribute("Pozitie", ExportModelMacheta[3]),
                    new XAttribute("FromatMacheta", "xls"),
                });
                results.Add(newExportModelMacheta);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might help to give a Delphi example of how to parse the XML you get
from your query.  However, as you can see from this q,
[How to Decode XML Blob field in D7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983728/how-to-decode-xml-blob-field-in-d7/40996148#40996148)
I ran into a problem decoding the contents of the blob field in which the XML is returned.

So, the code below implements a work-around to get the XML as a string rather than as a blob.
It then uses the MSXML xml-parser to parse the XML string into data-rows, fieldnames and
field values.

Note: this is written for Delphi 7, which I tend to use for SO answers when no specific
Delphi version is specified.  It may need minor alterations for later versions of
Delphi and/or the MSXML typelib import unit.

Also note that to use this code, you should not have persistent fields defined on the AdoQuery, because the code modifies the field-type of the data returned.

Code

```
Uses [...], MSXML;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  Output : AnsiString;
  i,
  j : Integer;
  XmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  NodeList : IXmlDOMNodeList;
  Attributes : IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap;
  AttrNode : IXmlDomNode;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create('');
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    //  the following line is to work around a problem decoding the blob field
    //  which you get when the query returms the XML as a blob
    AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select Convert(Text, (' + AdoQuery1.SQL.Text + '))';
    AdoQuery1.Open;
    TBlobField(AdoQuery1.Fields[0]).SaveToStream(SS);

    Output := SS.DataString;
    Memo1.Lines.Text := Output;

    //  As can be seen from the contents of Memo1, the contents of Output are not
    //  well-formed XML, just a series of nodes with the same name.  So, we surround them
    //  with a root node to make Output XML-parseable
    Output := '<data>' + Output + '</data>';

    XmlDoc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
    XmlDoc.Async := False;
    XmlDoc.LoadXml(Output);

    //  The following XPath query gets the data-row nodes of the XML
    NodeList := XmlDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes('/data/*');
    Assert(NodeList <> Nil);

    Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    for i := 0 to NodeList.Length - 1 do begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Row');
      Attributes := NodeList.item[I].Attributes;
      for j := 0 to Attributes.length - 1 do begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Field');
        AttrNode := Attributes.item[j];
        Memo1.Lines.Add(AttrNode.nodeName + ': ' + AttrNode.nodeValue);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('');
      end;
    end;

  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    XmlDoc := Nil;
    SS.Free;
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem , i exported my XML to delphi in a string and i use the parameteres from there to call my C# function.
Thank you for help.